# If $U$ and $V$ open in $S$ and if $f:S→\Bbb R^m$ agrees in $U$ and $V$ with a $C^r$ function then $f$ is a $C^r$ function too when $U\cup V=S$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ and let $U$ and $V$ open in $S$ whose union is $S$, so if $f:S\rightarrow\Bbb R^m$ agree in $U$ and $V$ with the $C^r$ functions $g$ and $h$  then $f$ is the $C^r$ function too.

So by the glue theorem the result is trivially true when $r=0$. But how to prove it for any $r>0$? And if the statement is generally false then what happens when $S$ is open? So could anyone help me, please?

Comment: You mean $f_{|U}$ and $f_{|V}$ are $C^r$, and $U\cup V=S$? Also $S$ is open? Being a $C^r$ function is a local property, meaning $f$ is $C^r$ iff $f$ is $C^r$ at any point. And $f$ being $C^r$ at a point $x_0$ can be deduced by considering arbitrary (small) open neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Yes, I mean that $U\cup V=S$ but generally I don't state that $S$ is open.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter whether $S$ is open or not. As I said, being $C^r$ is a local property. In case when $S$ is not open, then by the definition we additionally have to find a local $C^r$ extension of $f$ around every point.